# Large number of worker nodes v/s few worker nodes with more resources

Tags: kubernetes

Is it preferable to have a Kubernetes cluster with 4 nodes having resources 4 CPUs, 16 GB RAM or 2 nodes cluster with resources 8 CPUs and 32 GB RAM?

What benefits user will get if they go for horizontal scaling over vertical scaling in Kubernetes concepts.  I mean suppose we want to run 4 pods, is it good to go with 2 nodes cluster with resources 8 CPU and 32 GB RAM or 4 nodes cluster with resources  4 CPU and 16 GB RAM.

Answer (score 2):

In general I would recommend larger nodes because it's easier to place containers on them.

If you have a pod that `resources: {requests: {cpu: 2.5}}`, you can only place one of them on a 4-core node, and two on 2x 4-core nodes, but you can put 3 on a single 8-core node.

```
+----+----+----+----+    +----+----+----+----+
|-WORKLOAD--|       |    |-WORKLOAD--|       |
+----+----+----+----+    +----+----+----+----+

+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|-WORKLOAD--|--WORKLOAD--|-WORKLOAD--|  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

If you have 16 cores total and 8 cores allocated, it's possible that no single node has more than 2 cores free with 4x 4-CPU nodes, but you're guaranteed to be able to fit that pod with 2x 8-CPU nodes.

```
+----+----+----+----+    +----+----+----+----+
|-- USED -|         |    |-- USED -|         |
+----+----+----+----+    +----+----+----+----+
+----+----+----+----+    +----+----+----+----+
|-- USED -|         |    |-- USED -|         |
+----+----+----+----+    +----+----+----+----+

Where   |-WORKLOAD--| goes?

+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|------- USED ------|                   |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|------- USED ------|                   |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

At the specific scale you're talking about, though, I'd be a little worried about running a 2-node cluster: if a single node dies you've lost half your cluster capacity.  Unless I knew that I was running multiple pods that needed 2.0 CPU or more I might lean towards the 4-node setup here so that it will be more resilient in the event of node failure (and that does happen in reality).

Answer (score 2):

**Horizontal Autoscaling**

- Pros

  - Likely to have more capacity since you are expanding VMs or/and servers. You are essentially expanding your cluster.
  - In theory, more redundancy since you are spreading your workloads across different physical servers.
- Cons

  - In theory, it's slower. Meaning it's slower to provision servers and VMs than pods/containers in the same machine (for vertical autoscaling)
  - Also, you need to provision both servers/VMs and containers/pods when you scale up.
  - Doesn't work that well with plain bare-metal infrastructure/servers.

**Vertical Autoscaling**

- Pros

  - In theory, it should be faster to autoscale if you have large servers provisioned. (Also, faster response)
  - If you have data-intensive apps you might benefit from workloads running on the same machines.
  - Great if you have a few extra unused bare-metal servers.
- Cons

  - If you have large servers provisioned you may waste a lot of resources.
  - You need to calculate the capacity of your workloads more precisely (this could be a pro or a con depending on how you see it)
  - If you have a fixed set of physical servers, you will run into eventual limitations of CPUs, Storage, Memory, etc.

Generally, you'd want to have a combination of both Horizontal and Vertical autoscaling.